# ListView not refreshing after adding value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What i am doing is passing data through more than 2 pages. I assign viewmodel to next page while i am navigating. In second page i have a listview that is not refreshing/updating after adding a value.

Help me please!!

Here is my code

MyViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        public string _userName { get; set; }
        public List<family> familyList;
        public List<family> FamilyList
        {
            get { return familyList; }
            set
            {
                familyList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }       
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            _userName = "Mak";
            familyList = new List<family>();
        }
        public void AddMember(string memberName)
        {
            FamilyList.Add(new family
            {
                name = memberName,
                id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                username=_userName
            });
        }
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

**userdetails.xaml**

```
<cl:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="familyinfo.userdetails" xmlns:cl="clr-namespace:familyinfo;assembly=familyinfo">
<Label Font="Roboto-Medium" FontSize="14" Text="{Bindinbg _userName}" />
<Button Clicked="Next_Step" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderRadius="12" Text="NEXT" />
</cl:BasePage>
```

**userdetails.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class userdetails : BasePage
    {
        public MyViewModel _myViewModel { get; set; }
        public userdetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
        }
        void Next_Step(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _myViewModel =(MyViewModel) this.BindingContext;
            var familyMember = new FamilyMember();
            familyMember.BindingContext = _myViewModel;
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavPage(registerCar);
         }
     }
```

**FamilyMember.xaml**

```
 <cl:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="familyinfo.FamilyMember" xmlns:cl="clr-namespace:familyinfo;assembly=familyinfo">
    <Label Font="Roboto-Medium" FontSize="14" Text="{Bindinbg _userName}" />
<cl:CustomEntry x:Name="txtMemberName" Placeholder="Member Name" FontSize="12" /> 
<Button Clicked="AddMember" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderRadius="12" Text="Add" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyList}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.View>
                                <Grid Padding="20,10,0,0" ColumnSpacing="12" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
                                        </RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="0" Font="Roboto-Medium" FontSize="14" TextColor="#000000" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell.View>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </cl:BasePage>
```

**FamilyMember.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class FamilyMember : BasePage
    {
        public MyViewModel _myViewModel { get; set; }
        public userdetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         void AddMember(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
         _myViewModel = (MyViewModel)this.BindingContext;
        _myViewModel.AddMember(txtMemberName.Text);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Atul: Using an `ObservableCollection` is the right way to do it.

A workaround - if you don't have a chance to change that - is to set the `ListView`'s `ItemSource` to `null` and back to the list, whenever data changed and the UI needs to update:

```
void UpdateListView(ListView listView)
{
    var itemsSource = listView.ItemsSource;
    listView.ItemsSource = null;
    listView.ItemsSource = itemsSource;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Falko for you valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Atul: Feel free to upvote/accept any of the given answers if they helped you with your problem. This not only motivates users to write answers of great quality, but also helps other readers to quickly identify good approaches worth trying out.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, you must use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface (instead of the well known `INofifyPropertyChanged`). And that's exactly what does `ObservableCollection<T>` for you. This is why it works like "magic".

Comment: Agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I just used `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` and it works!!

Comment: You have to use an observable for binding otherwise the UI has no way of knowing something changed. I suggest you look at the ObservableRangeCollection in the [MVVM Helpers](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) library.